# How to compare order of string representation of integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to compare the values of the numbers the strings represent:

for example:

```
a="6"
b="10"
c="5"
```

now I want to compare:
`a<c` (it gives False which is correct) `and b>c` (it gives False which is incorrect) because In python < and > operators applied on strings compare them using lexicographic order.

if we use rjust then:

```
a=a.rjust(len(b), '0')  #output: a='06'
```

now,

```
a="06"
b="10"
c="5"
```

again try to compare:

```
a<b (it gives True which is correct) and b>c (it gives False which is again incorrect).
```

I am stuck in that case how to compare that case which gives in both case result true.

Comment: Can't you convert them to an integer?

Comment: No because in the database it is Char field.

Comment: Well then you can read them in python and convert them to integer, will make your life much easier

Comment: `int(b)>int(c)` ?

Comment: but it doesn't change the database column field.

Comment: why not use sql query to compare there itself, instead of using python

Comment: Depending on what you want to do - comparing the integers or updating the cells in database? Just for comparison purpose, converting the stings to integers will make your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = '6'
b = '10'
c = '5'
```

Now

```
ord('6') = 54
ord('1') = 49, ord('0') = 48
ord('5') = 53
```

When two string is compared to each other they are compared using their ASCII value, one by one.

for `a<c`
means `53<54 [False]`

for `b>c`
first `49>53 [False]`
and this evaluates to False.

[image]

This is how string comparison works.

For your answer, you can typecast these variable to an integer.

```
int(b)>int(c) [True]
int(a)<int(c) [False]
```

Comment: yes exactly, but we can manipulate it using rjust as i already did see above my code.

a="05"
b="10"
c="04"
a<c  #output False
if is compare their ASCII value, one by one. then, why this condition False